# How to represent an SQL query in an easily understandable, universal format?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am planning a C# query tool which is to facilitate the creation of queries, to be used by individuals who have absolutely no knowledge of SQL.

I would like to display the user's query in a format which is easily understandable.  Two options which I thought of are Venn Diagrams or natural language.  An example of the latter case (to further elaborate on the question) could be:

The user uses the tool and the SQL statement generated by the tool would be something like `SELECT SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES`.

The tool could display the query as an easily understandable format, such as: "The report is going to display the salary of all employees".

That could be one approach - by using natural language techniques.  Another could be by presenting Venn Diagrams, as many people can understand this notation.

Are there any other ways of representing the query, which could be easily understood?

Comment: A Venn Diagram seems not to be intuitive (if you look at anything else than joins). I like the MS SQL Server Management Studio approach for Views, where you have every field of an table listed and can check them if you want to see them.
It's not perfect but okay ...

Comment: Given all the possibilities in SQL (JOIN-variants, subqueries, etc.) not to speak of other "technical" stuff sometimes required (optimizer hints, etc.) any approach will quickly become as "convoluted" as SQL itself could be considered sometimes (or worse). Interesting, nevertheless.

Comment: How do you plan to define the terminology, e.g. does _salary_ include bonuses, are contractors _employees_, ... ?  You might want to have a look at [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to see how it tries to explain what it is doing.

Comment: That sql statement was just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natural language is probally the best option, Venn Diagrams could confuse people. Easiest approach would be to give a couple of people some SQL training so they can make their own repports and and also act as a gate-keeper for other types of repports they can't make themself. We use this approach and it works very well.

Comment: Natural language does seem to be the best option.  I'd like to see some other options so that I could consider everything first though :)

Comment: You can make a monster of a view and flatten the database, bad for performance easy to use for noobs..:-)

Answer (score 1):

What do you say about Query Trees?

[image]

Comment: Seems a bit too complicated as the users of this tool will have a very basic database/SQL background.  Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 0):

As already commented on other asnwer, Venn diagrams are not easy to understand for eveyone, even less for non technical users. From previous experiences working with clients asking for similar funcionalities I suggest taking a couple of their most *advanced* users and go hard on them teaching how to use some reporting tool. Configure the tool and let them play **a lot** with it giving them some feedback and help. Finally after a while, if correctly done, you can leave them *on the wild* at those advanced users will do the job.